# Homeomorphic to a circle

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X:=[a,b]\times [c,d] \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with the subspace topology and let $U$ be an open connected set in $X$.
Show that the boundary of $U$ is homeomorphic to a circle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wat have you tried? Have you tried making a picture to see what this is true?

Comment: If you show us what you have tried perhaps someone can use work to provide a more approprite hint.

Comment: This is not true in general you should add somthing like $a< b$ and $c<d$, because in this case it obviously doesn' work

Comment: Everyone is staying up tonight....

Answer (score 2):

Let $U$ be an open annulus in $X$.  Then the statement is not true.

Comment: In general it is homeomorphic to a circle or the union of two disjoint circles?
Can you show me how to prove it?

Comment: @user73577, you should consider more examples...